# Looking for a perfect word to replace my phrase in the lyrics

Tags: single-word-requests

I am working on a lyric.

This is about a girl who smiles at a boy whom she is interested and also ignores him on the other day .. she wasn't sure whether she want him or not.

To accomplish this scenario, I wrote the line as

> You smile a day and **ignore** other day !!

I prefer to replace the word "ignore" and so wrote "hurt". Still I am looking for a better word.

> You smile a day and hurt other day !!

Opposite of smile - Keeping the face in an anger mode or ignorance mode.

Comment: Perhaps *sneer* or *scorn* could work; *frown* is another option. Also try their synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just improvising here, not going for the word, but the line:

*You smile a day **and turn your back another***

*You smile a day **and frown another day***

Answer (score 3):

You smile a day and

Walk past me another day

or

Look away another day

or

Turn away another day

Answer (score 0):

- You smile at me one day, and *give me the cold shoulder* the next.

This is a **fixed phrase** meaning to ignore, perhaps intentionally.